# _CastError (type 'Future<DateTime>' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I'm following a tutorial that makes use of class `WorldTime` that represents data fetched from the worldtimeapi.org website. Having completed, I wanted to make changes to support more functionality.

I altered the class `WorldTime` so that it has a method that must return a `DateTime` object. The method is asynchronous so instead it returns a `Future<DateTime>` (earlier it didn't return anything).

```
class WorldTime {
.
.
. 
  Future<DateTime> getTime() async {
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now() ;   

    try {     
      Response response = await get(Uri.parse("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url")) ;     
      Map dataMap = jsonDecode(response.body) ;
     
      String dt = dataMap['datetime'] ;
     
      String sign = dataMap['utc_offset'].substring(0, 1) ;       
      String hoursOffset = dataMap['utc_offset'].substring(1, 3) ;   
      String minsOffset = dataMap['utc_offset'].substring(4, 6) ;    
     
      dateTime = DateTime.parse(dt) ;      

      if (sign == '+') {
        dateTime = dateTime.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(hoursOffset))) ;
        dateTime = dateTime.add(Duration(minutes: int.parse(minsOffset))) ;
      }
      else {
        dateTime = dateTime.subtract(Duration(hours: int.parse(hoursOffset))) ;
        dateTime = dateTime.subtract(Duration(minutes: int.parse(minsOffset))) ;
      }
     
      time = DateFormat.jm().format(dateTime) ;   // set the time property

      isDay = dateTime.hour > 6 && dateTime.hour < 19 ? true : false ; 
    }
    catch (e) {
      print("\n\nError caught:\n $e") ;
      time = "Could not fetch time" ;
    }

    return dateTime ;
  }
}
```

In the class that represents the home page of the app, the code must call the `getTime()` method of an instance of `WorldTime`. So I wrote this:

```
DateTime currentDateTime = worldTimeData.getTime() as DateTime;
```

Once I run the code I get this error and the app fails to run.

```
_CastError (type 'Future<DateTime>' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast)
```

In attempt to solving this, I tried:

```
DateTime currentDateTime =  DateTime.parse(worldTimeData.getTime().toString()) ;
```

which results in:

```
FormatException (FormatException: Invalid date format
Instance of 'Future<DateTime>')
```

How do I get about this? I need to be able to obtain a `DateTime` object upon calling the `getTime()` method of an instance of `WorldTime`. I'm new to Flutter and appreciate your help.

Comment: Typically you would `await` a `Future<X>` in order to get back an `X`. See [Working with futures: async and await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await).

Comment: @mmcdon20 thanks for pointing this out! I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

**getTime()** is async function and returns Future. Therefore you must use await when you call.

```
DateTime currentDateTime = await worldTimeData.getTime();
```